# CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT - Caching bad responses?

Tags: curl, nginx, dns, php

I have some DNS issues with the curl requests my php application is making.

nginx+php5-fpm logging is showing slow scripts with the point of failure being curl.

Confused because my curl scripts have the timeout and connect timeouts options set both to 3 seconds (production server).

So occasionally I get blips of errors where my scripts fail. I simulated DNS failure and I can re-create these php script timeout failure.

So randomly my curl is doing it's DNS lookup and failing. Either the DNS server is failing to respond, or it is throttling us back (we're sending hundreds of requests per second at peak).

I think I need to work toward a local DNS cache but for now is there anything I can do to limit the bad DNS responses or DNS timeouts with curl?

I was thinking, does `CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT` cache bad responses too? If yes, I need to turn this off, if it doesn't cache any response / timeout then I could increase it from 2 to say 15 minutes to help matters perhaps?

Any ideas on how I stop curl & bad DNS from crashing my site?

Comment: Disappointingly with further testing, if i execute a curl command to a domain with CURL DNS Caching turned on, if i then simulate DNS failure by putting 1.1.1.1 in the resolv.conf - it will not pull the IP from the CURL DNS Cache... So i dont see what the point of that curl option is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this info from the man page will be useful for others finding this question:

> CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT
>
> Pass a long, this sets the timeout in seconds. Name resolves will be kept in memory for this number of seconds. Set to zero to completely disable caching, or set to -1 to make the cached entries remain forever. By default, libcurl caches this info for 60 seconds.
>
> NOTE: the name resolve functions of various libc implementations don't re-read name server information unless explicitly told so (for example, by calling res_init(3)). This may cause libcurl to keep using the older server even if DHCP has updated the server info, and this may look like a DNS cache issue to the casual libcurl-app user.

From http://linux.die.net/man/3/curl_easy_setopt

Answer (score 0):

I generally have bind9 running on my servers so that what will cache my domain names. This is generally much better than hoping for others to do it for you.

You are not very clear on how you use `curl` but the cache option works only if you continue running. If you run a script which exists and get restarted later, then the cache will be lost each time. Indeed.

If trying to access your own services, maybe you should use an entry in your `/etc/hosts` file (as shown below) instead of relying on a full DNS. If you only access domains that your control, you would also be controlling their IP addresses.

```
1.2.3.4    foo.example.com
```

That would always work.

If instead you are dealing with many domain names that you have no control over, I'm afraid that having a properly working DNS is the only good solution. In that case, you may want to consider using bind9 and set it up to cache your domain names *for a long time* (1h to 2h is generally considered safe, 1 day or more may be much if the name changes you could have failures for near to 24 hours.